# In C, why does this function return false when conditions are met for it to return true?

Tags: c, function, printing, boolean, cs50

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

// Max number of candidates
#define MAX 9

// Candidates have name and vote count
typedef struct
{
    string name;
    int votes;
}
candidate;

// Array of candidates
candidate candidates[MAX];

// Number of candidates
int candidate_count;

// Function prototypes
bool vote(string name);
void print_winner(void);

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    // Check for invalid usage
    if (argc < 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: plurality [candidate ...]\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // Populate array of candidates
candidate_count = argc - 1;
if (candidate_count > MAX)
{
    printf("Maximum number of candidates is %i\n", MAX);
    return 2;
}
for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
{
    candidates[i].name = argv[i] + 1;
    candidates[i].votes = 0;
}

int voter_count = get_int("Number of voters: ");

// Loop over all voters
for (int i = 0; i < voter_count; i++)
{
    string name = get_string("Vote: ");

    // Check for invalid vote
    if (!vote(name))
    {
        printf("Invalid vote.\n");
    }
}

// Display winner of election
print_winner();
}

// Update vote totals given a new vote
bool vote(string name)
{
    //variable index
    int x;

    //loop through candidate names to find a match with the input name, add a ballot if there is a 
    match
    for (x = 0;  x < candidate_count; x++)
        {
            if (strcmp(candidates[x].name, name) == 0)
            {
                candidates[x].votes++;
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
}
```

This code looks to see if a user input string matches an argument string by way of function vote. I don't understand why it keeps printing "Invalid Vote" as if the function returns false when the correct name is given, and the function should return true. When I flip the true and false returns, the program works. This makes no sense at all to me and I'm on the verge of just thinking that I can't think in a way that i can code anything successfully. Thanks for your time whoever reads this, if anyone does.

Comment: What is `get_string`?  Does it return input fro the user as some allocated string?  Does it include a trailing newline?  Does the input match against one of the expected strings *exactly*?

Comment: @jamesdlin It's part of the cs50 library.  Tag added.

Comment: Okay, so it's obviously part of some library, answer @jamesdlin's other questions please. What does it return?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not reading in the names correctly here:

```
for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
{
    candidates[i].name = argv[i] + 1;
    candidates[i].votes = 0;
}
```

This is getting each string from the second character on, starting with the argument which contains the name of the program.

You put the `+1` in the wrong place.  What you want is:

```
    candidates[i].name = argv[i + 1];
```

Comment: That's what I thought as I read the code, but everything above the vote function is supplied to me and with that, should not need to be changed for the program to run properly. I noticed exactly what you pointed out, but am following instructions per the course. If this is what the problem is, I'm going to be pissed I wasted this much of my life on this lol.